# Limiting Keywords with jQuery by counting commas?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a CMS to allow users to add keywords to their profiles, but I'm wanting to limit that to 10 keywords, which are comma-delimited, by counting the number of commas (in this case, 9).

Any ideas on how to go about doing this with jQuery? I'll be doing a double-check on the server-side, but I'd like a quick little, live error checker on the front-end.

Comment: Try these http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of counting commas, how about splitting them then get the length.

```
var count = 'reigel,me,you,we'.split(',').length; // results 4
```

[fiddle to see](http://jsfiddle.net/8gydA/).

and if you're using this in a `<form>`, you could edit the submit handler like this,

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){
    if ($('#inputTextId').val().split(',').length < 10) {
        return false; // prevent page from submitting...
    }
})​;​
```

[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gydA/1/)

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>
<sub>Don't forget to accept an answer</sub>

Comment: Awesome answer. I've implemented something similar to your second suggestion and it works great. Thanks so much for your help!